# Firebase: How to get email from sign in with apple on real device?

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I'm implementing a sign in with apple, this is my code on apple button press

```
  onAppleButtonPress = async () => {
// performs login request
const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
  requestedOperation: AppleAuthRequestOperation.LOGIN,
  requestedScopes: [
    AppleAuthRequestScope.EMAIL,
    AppleAuthRequestScope.FULL_NAME,
  ],
});

// Ensure Apple returned a user identityToken
if (!appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken) {
  console.log('no token');
  throw 'Apple Sign-In failed - no identify token returned';
}

// Create a Firebase credential from the response
const {identityToken, nonce} = appleAuthRequestResponse;
const appleCredential = firebaseAuth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(
  identityToken,
  nonce,
);


//I WANT TO GET THE EMAIL HERE TO USE CHECK IT FROM FIREBASE IF EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS BY THIS CODE

firebaseAuth()
        .fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(appleAuthRequestResponse.email)
        .then(providers => {

});

}
```

It works on the simulator, but on real device the email is null.
Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple only returns the full name and email on the first login, it will return null on the succeeding login so you need to save those data.

T receive these again, go to your device settings; `Settings > Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes & App Store > Password & Security > Apps Using Your Apple ID`, tap on your app and tap Stop Using Apple ID. You can now sign-in again and you'll receive the full name and `email.

Source [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication#faqs).

Comment: Am I going to save the email locally in the first login in order for me to get the email?

Comment: not sure how you can clear the cache on iOS. If they remove the app app from using apple id from their settlings, my assumption would be that you would get it again, because it would then be a 'new' user.

Comment: Saved my day, thanks!